# Responsive is not working?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was trying to make some images responsive but failing everytime.

This is my html codes

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"> 
    <div style="margin-top:30px;"><img src="nature/logo.png"></div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="socials">

        </div>  

        <div class="nature">
                <ul class="reset">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nature/img7.png"alt="" /></a></li>
                <li> <a onClick="javascript:sendpage();" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="nature/img2.png"alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nature/mg3.png"alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nature/img4.png"alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nature/img5.png"alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nature/img6.png"alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="nature/img4.png"alt="" /></a></li>
          </ul> 
        </div>  

    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

and this following this css file

```
.nature {
display:block;
width:150px;
height:150px;
background:url(../nature/img1.png) no-repeat;
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
}

.socials, .nature {
margin:0 auto;
}

.socials {
margin-bottom:50px;
}

ul.reset,
ul.reset li {
display:block;
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
}

ul.reset li {
position:absolute;
}

ul.reset li a {
outline:none;
}
```

I have tried changing all px into percentile and also tried adding some media queries but nothing is happening im unable to find the problem

Any suggestion will be great for my learning experience.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: responsive is quite a broad term. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to make following thing responsive

http://plugindetector.com/mobilyblocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make responsive images is to set their width to 100% so taht they inherit the containers width. Also set a minimum and maximum width in order to provide some boundaries.
also set height to auto.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vU9G4/5/

```
<div class="nature">
    <ul class="reset">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://d1c739w2xm33i4.cloudfront.net/2.2/top_image.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.nature {
    width:100%
    background:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
}


ul.reset li {
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
}

ul.reset li a {
    outline:none;
}

ul.reset li a img{
    min-width:240px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto
}
```

Comment: Are thing is im trying to make this www.plugindetector.com/mobilyblocks  think in responsive and not happening tried ur way :(

Comment: Make sure that js scripts are not interfering with your styling.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have defined style for . The following should probably fix it.

```
.nature img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No its making my images coming coming down

Answer (score 0):

```
.nature img{
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

or you can use jquery like this..

[responsive images](http://responsiveimg.com/)